# How can I increase letters gap?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

How can I increase the gap between two letters in the same word in libreoffice writer (version 7.2 and above)?

For instance, the word "word" would have each letters more spaced between each other (without using any specific character in-between, like a space).

It might be something in the menu: *format > paragraph >* *...???*  but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Format / Characters, then the third tab (Position), Spacing, Character Spacing field

Comment: In the English version, it is Format -> Characters -> Position -> Spacing -> Character Spacing.

Comment: (answer edited to reflect @ReddyLutonadio 's comment)